# Unity3D, storing data in subclasses

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a Unity3D game,

I want to store data on a variety of subclasses, all of which are derived from a single class `Tool` and be able to retrieve it at will, as well as iterate through each of the classes.

For example, one tool is `Hammer` and I want to store the total number of times any hammer was used in the level in something like `int timesUsed`.  Static properties seems like the way to handle this but I can't find a way to easily iterate through all subclasses of `Tool` at once and retrieve their `timesUsed` property.

To clarify, I want each subclass of `Tool` to possess `timeUsed`.  So `Hammer`, `Drill`, and `Saw` all have independent `timesUsed` properties.  But each instance of `Hammer` will always have the same `timesUsed`.

Another short example, each `Tool` subclass such as `Hammer` would have a link to the text box for "Hammer".  This text box would the same for all instances of that class.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Maybe numRemaining isn't the way.. You probably need some sort of "ToolRepository" or "ToolPool" class that can be accessible as static singleton -> allowing you to both count your Tools and also retrieve only Tools of specific subtype

Comment: Just to clarify... You have base class `tool` and you have `Hammer`.. if you have 10 hammers ... you want to define 1 or 10 classes from Hammer ....?

Comment: Each `Hammer` would be its own instance.  That's where static properties could come in, since they live on the `Hammer` class itself.  The property `public static numRemaining` on the `Hammer` class would equal 10 in this case.

Comment: dude, DO NOT USE STATICS.  it's like you do not use globals in programming.  Statics just don't work in Unity - it is an ECS system.  Forget about statics.

Comment: @JoeBlow lol These static questions keeps popping up nonstop.

Comment: Are the tools meant to be instantiated (so `Tool` derives from `MonoBehaviour`)?

Comment: The `numRemaining` example was a bad one.  I actually want to track properties that are specific to the `Tool` subclass (e.g. `Hammer`) but not any particular instance of that subclass.  A better example might be `timesUsed` that tracks how many times ANY `Hammer` has been used.  All `Hammer` classes would update the same variable.

Comment: @GunnarB. `Tool` does indeed derive from `MonoBehavior`.

Comment: @JoeBlow Looking into ECS now.  Thanks for the heads up, this is helpful.

Comment: Ok, another example just to see if I understood it now: There are, lets say, 10 hammers in the level. Per level the player has a certain number of times of how often he can use an item of type hammer, say 20. Every time he uses any of the hammers in the level, that 20 goes down by 1 and if it's down to 0 he can't use any of the hammers in the level anymore (or whatever rule applies). This about right?

Comment: @GunnarB. Yes!  This would be one of a number of properties which would be shared amongst the `Hammer` class.

Comment: Added another example of storing a reference to a text box.

Comment: Hmm, I actually right now don't have a good solution for this. I'd suggest to create a new question. Use my example, I think that discribes it relativly clear. Use for example `Referencing the same class from multiple GameObjects` as title and discribe your `base class to sub classes` relation. Also say in which points the sub class are different (like what should be part of the base class and what comes with the sub classes). That should get you some more attention.

Answer (score 4):

> Each Hammer would be its own instance. That's where static properties
>   could come in

No. You don't need static here.

> Each Hammer would be its own instance.

Use List to hold each `Hammer` instance.

```
public class Tool
{
    private List<Hammer> hammers;

    public Tool()
    {
        hammers = new List<Hammer>();

    }

    public void addNewHammer()
    {
        hammers.Add(new Hammer());
    }

    public void addNewHammer(int amount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            hammers.Add(new Hammer());
        }
    }

    public void removeHammer(int index)
    {
        hammers.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void removeAllHammer()
    {
        hammers.Clear();
    }

    public int getRemainingNum(int index)
    {
        return hammers[index].getRemainingNum();
    }

    public Hammer getCurrentHammerInstance(int index)
    {
        return hammers[index];
    }

    public Hammer[] getAllHammerInstance()
    {
        return hammers.ToArray();
    }
}

public class Hammer
{
    private int numRemaining = 0;
    public int getRemainingNum()
    {
        return numRemaining;
    }
}
```

How to Use:

```
void Start()
{
    Tool mytools = new Tool();

    //Add 1 new Hammer
    mytools.addNewHammer();

    //Add 10 Hammers
    mytools.addNewHammer(10);


    //Get numRemaining
    mytools.getRemainingNum(0);

    //Remove a Hammer by index
    mytools.removeHammer(0);

    //Remove all Hammers
    mytools.removeAllHammer();

    //Get Hammer instance
    Hammer myhammer = mytools.getCurrentHammerInstance(0);

    //Get All Hammer instance as array
    Hammer[] allHammers = mytools.getAllHammerInstance();

    //Loop through all numRemaining from each hammer
    for (int i = 0; i < allHammers.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(allHammers[i].getRemainingNum());
    }
}
```

**Important**: *You can convert this into **generics** using `T` and be able to add other tools. The functions will no longer be locked to `Hammers` and can then be used with other Tools/Classes.*

Comment: Having a list of `<Hammer>` and then having that class hold a counter doesn't really make sense. (The question meant multiple different tools (hammer, axe, ...) and having a counter for those each.)

Comment: @GunnarB. I thought he said he wants to store many sub-classes in a class called `Tools`. For example sub class called `Hammer` in a class called tools then needs a way to access `numRemaining` of the sub-class? Then he wants to be able to tell how many hammers left in a `numRemaining` variable.  This is what I understood from the question. Maybe I got it all wrong....

Comment: @GunnarB. dude look again, P's approach is perfect.

Comment: He meant that `Tool` is a base class and each individual tool (e.g. `Hammer`) is a sub class of this and he needs to keep track of how many of each tool type he has currently.

Comment: This definitely works for maintaining a count but there would be other properties too.  Durability, repairAmt, etc.  These don't fold so easily into an existing method and they'd need to be shared across all hammer instances.

Comment: @GunnarB. He never mentioned base in his question. Anyways, doing it this way should work too. It should.

Comment: "These don't fold so easily into an existing method" what does that mean?

Comment: "I want to store data on a variety of subclasses, all of which are derived from a single class `Tool`" - this implies a `base class - sub class` relation to me ;)

Comment: Yes, making this generic would definitly simplify the overall handling if the amount of different tools gets big.

Comment: @Preston I was still typing this before you made your comment. I have no idea what you are talking about when you said folding but in my edit, I mentioned that you can convert the function into generics. I did not use generics because I like to make stuff simple as possible. You can do that yourself and this will work for every other tools/classes.

Answer (score 1):

As rudolf_franek suggested, have a manager class that keeps track of all your tools (the typical list of instantiated objects).

```
public class Tool : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int durability;
    public string name;
}
```

Certain tool, e.g. Hammer:

```
public class Hammer : Tool
{
    public void HammerAction(){...}
}
```

A manager (this should probably be a singleton):

```
public class ToolManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<Hammer> hammers;

    public int GetHammerCount()
    {
        return hammers.Count;
    }

    // other stuff like adding when instantiating etc.
}
```

Note that deriving from `MonoBehaviour` means that you can't create a tool/subclass of tool by saying `new Tool()`, but instead requires some unity way of doing it like `Instantiate()`.

---

Examples of Property in c#/Unity (by Joe Blow)

```
private float _ordinaryMps;
public float OrdinaryMps
    {
    set {
        _ordinaryMps = value;
        foreach(BaseFrite e in all)
            e.mpsNow = _ordinaryMps * widthSpeedFactor;
        }
    get { return _ordinaryMps; }
    }

private float _mps;
public float Mps
    {
    set {
        _mps = value;
        for (int i=0; i<kParts; ++i)
            parts[i].mps = Mps;
        }
    get { return _mps; }
    }

public int Count
    {
    get { return prepped != null ? prepped.Count : 0; }
    }

private int _hearts;
public int Hearts
    {
    set {
        _hearts = value;
        controls.HeartNumber(_hearts);
        }
    get { return _hearts; }
    }

private int _megabombs;
public int Megabombs
    {
    set {
        _megabombs = value;
        controls.MegabombNumber(_megabombs);
        }
    get { return _megabombs; }
    }
```

Comment: dude in your scheme GetHammerCount would be a property, that is cooler.  (it's no different - you just feel cooler doing it)

Comment: note however that such a property already exists  :)  ".Count"  (or "Length" or something, I always forget).  Code would just look like "tools.hammers.Count" or "tools.bolts.Count"

Comment: you shouldn't use class/variable names like "ToolsManager" or "xFloat" or "tracksList" or "vertsArray" and so on. Of course, you just say "Tools" "x" "tracks" "verts".  Don't include a "species" or Type or other description in naming.

Comment: I actually meant to use `.Count` for `GetHammerCount`. Confused that with c++. I did the naming just so you don't have a class `Tool` and a class `Tools`. Thats too similar.

Comment: Dude you went all head over ass  :)

Comment: Dude you're totally wrong about "Tool" "Tools".  In *almost every Unity project* you have Bullet, Bullets, Dinosaur, Dinosaurs, etc - because of pooling.  It's absolutely idiomatic.  Give it love

Comment: Yes, you can do it if you know what you mean, but this is for showing so he doesn't confuse names.

Comment: This OP looks like is new to Unity. I hope you let him that if you derive  `Tool`  from `MonoBehaviour` like you did in your answer, you can no longer use the `new` keyword to create new instance of `Tool`. If you do, it will crash Unity. It would be good to provide an example that uses your method. That way he won't have to ask another question or wonder why your code is not working.

Comment: @Programmer Well, I commented "when instantiating", but I admit that this is not clearly stating that this should use `Instantiate()`.

Comment: @Programmer Actually this should probably be with multiple `List<GameObject> hammer/axe/otherTool` and use prefabs of each tool type.

Comment: @GunnarB. I don't understand you but being new, he wont know that. I've answered more than 5 questions about that this week. Also when people say they want to store data, assume that it is a plain data. Application data and there is no need to derive from Monobehaviour. Assuming he mentioned Rigidbody or other Unity components then you can derive Monobehaviour but show how to use it.

Comment: @Programmer Yes, actually for me it is logically pretty clear that tools and derivatives should be MonoBehaviour so they can be added as Components and the corresponding gameobjects work as individual objects in the scene (with durability etc.), but I have to consider what the questioner might know and what not.

Answer (score -1):

If you keep each tool it it's own collection the count of the collection is the number of tools of that type.

If you keep all the tools in a single collection you can get the number of tools by getting the count of each tool using .OfType() for example.

If you don't plan on using collections to hold your tool objects you can use a static property approach that is a reference count of your object which you can increment in your constructor and decrement in dispose. Or you can create a .Use() method or some such, you don't have to use IDispose.

Here is an example of the non collection count abstract property approach you might be looking for.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    namespace UnitTestProject1
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {
                Hammer hammer1 = new Hammer();
                Hammer hammer2 = new Hammer();                    
                Assert.AreEqual(2, hammer1.NumRemaining);

                // Calling dispose doesn't set hammer1 null, just decrements the _numRemaining count
                hammer1.Dispose();

                Saw saw1 = new Saw();
                Saw saw2 = new Saw();
                var tools = new List<Tool> {hammer1, hammer2, saw1, saw2};

                foreach (Tool tool in tools)
                {
                    if (tool is Hammer)
                        Assert.AreEqual(1, tool.NumRemaining);
                    if (tool is Saw)
                        Assert.AreEqual(2, tool.NumRemaining);
                }
            }
        }

        public abstract class Tool
        {
            public abstract int NumRemaining { get; }
        }

        public class Hammer : Tool, IDisposable
        {
            private static int _numRemaining;

            public Hammer()
            {
                _numRemaining++;
            }

            public override int NumRemaining
            {
                get { return _numRemaining; }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _numRemaining--;
            }
        }

        public class Saw : Tool, IDisposable
        {
            private static int _numRemaining;

            public Saw()
            {
                _numRemaining++;
            }

            public override int NumRemaining
            {
                get { return _numRemaining; }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _numRemaining--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is Unity. `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;` is not available. Using Dispose a-lot in a GameEngine/Unity is not a good idea. You get spikes and other performance problems.